# Rename multiple folder names based on Text file

Tags: python, bash

I would like to rename folders name in specific path based on text list I will provide.
for example , I have folders list structure as following :

```
 /home/XXX-01/$file1
 /home/XXX-12/$file2
 /home/XXX-23/$file66
 /home/XXX-32/$file44
 /home/XXX-123/$file65
```

and rand.txt file with details what folder name need to be change to , for example

```
XXX-22
XXX-33
XXX-55
XXX-4321
XXX-24456
```

the final folder structure would be like

```
 /home/XXX-22/$file1
 /home/XXX-33/$file2
 /home/XXX-55/$file66
 /home/XXX-4321/$file44
 /home/XXX-24456/$file65
```

thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: How do you assciate the original directory name with the target directory name?
In other words, how we can sort the original directories? With the number
after "XXX-" or with the filename in the directory? 2nd question: is there any chance the original directory name collide with the target directory name?

Comment: I don't think we need to sort the original directory, we just need to rename folder name in same order in rand.txt file./home/XXX-01/$file1  <-- XXX-22 == /home/XXX-22/$file1.the files pattern inside the 'XXX-$' folder in change from folder to folder

Comment: How do you define the **order**? There are no orders among directory names or file names unless you define a rule.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk version 4.0.2

```
 awk 'NR==FNR { # Process the list of directories (direcs.txt)
                map[NR]=$0 # Create an array indexed by the number record and with the directory as the value
              } 
      NR!=FNR { # Process the output of the find command
                
                newpath=gensub("(/home/)(.*)(/.*$)","\\1"map[NR]"\\3",$0); # Create the new path using the entry in the map array
                newdir=gensub("(/home/)(.*)(/.*.txt$)","\\1"map[num],$0) # Create the directory to create.
                print "mkdir "newdir # Print the mkdir command
                print "mv "$0" "newpath # Print the command to execute
              }' direcs.txt <(find /home -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*[[:digit:]]+.*$")
```

One liner:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR {map[NR]=$0} NR!=FNR { newpath=gensub("(/home/)(.*)(/.*.txt$)","\\1"map[NR]"\\3",$0);newdir=gensub("(/home/)(.*)(/.*.txt$)","\\1"map[num],$0);print "mkdir "newdir;print "mv "$0" "newpath }' direcs.txt <(find /home -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*[[:digit:]]+.*$")
```

Once you are happy that the commands look as expected, execute by piping through to bash/sh and so

```
 awk 'NR==FNR {map[NR]=$0} NR!=FNR { newpath=gensub("(/home/)(.*)(/.*.txt$)","\\1"map[NR]"\\3",$0);newdir=gensub("(/home/)(.*)(/.*.txt$)","\\1"map[num],$0);print "mkdir "newdir;print "mv "$0" "newpath }' direcs.txt <(find /home/robbo -regextype posix-extended -regex "^.*[[:digit:]]+.*$") | bash
```

Comment: thank you - my bad ,there is no specific files pattern under folders 'XXX-? ' I have to rename based on file I will provide , folder names in rand.txt will be sort by same order as I have to rename the folder in /home/XXX-? directory. I edit the post accordantly - I hope it more clear now.

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer.